# Find first element in list above certain frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a list of frozensets of integers, how can I find the first element which appears above some certain frequency?

There is a condition in an algorithm I am implementing involving hypergraph dualization.

Given two hypergraphs G (implemented as a tuple (G0,G1)) where G0 is the set of vertices and G1 is a list of frozensets(hyperedges) of vertices  and similarly for H (it is important to note that G0 = H0 always).

The pseudocode of the algorithm says to find, within the G1 and H1, any x (**which is guaranteed to be found because of some theory**) in either G1 OR H1 (presumably the fastest one you can find) such that the frequency of x is >= 1/log(|G1|+|H1|).

I did it naively as:

```
def logOrMore(v,edges,sum):
    count = 0
    for edge in edges:
        if v in edge:
            count+=1
    if count >= (1/log(sum)):
        return True
    return False
```

and in the main algorithm:

```
...code...
sum = len(G[1])+len(H[1])
x = 0
for v in G[0]:
    if logOrMore(v,G[1],sum):
        x = v
        break
if x ==0:
     for v in G[0]:
        if logOrMore(v,H[1],sum):
            x = v
            break
...more code...
```

This is becoming a big problem when the hypergraphs are huge. How can I do this in the fastest way possible?

An example of a G1 is

```
G1 = [frozenset({74, 76}), frozenset({73, 74, 29, 30}), frozenset({73, 74, 3, 4}), frozenset({74, 76, 29, 30}), frozenset({16, 73, 74}), frozenset({73, 74})]
```

but this is a very small case. It can get up to the point where there are more than 1000 frozensets inside the list.

**Note: The frozensets of integers are not sorted most of the time**

This is in Python 3.6.4 if that helps

Comment: I'm only unsure about you mentioning order and unsorted frozensets. Sets are by definition unsorted since they are not ordered, is that relevant to your requirements?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon It is not relevant. Its just that the Hypergraphs are being pulled from text files, and sometimes (rarely) the frozensets(hyperedges) happen to be sorted because the text file will have an edge listed as (1,2,3,4,5,6) for example. I do not expect them to be nor does it have any implication in the theory. I just mentioned it in case it did matter for your purposes of helping

Comment: Do they need to be frozensets? Using another data structure opens up a lot of possibilities.

Comment: @smallpants I mean, they dont NEED to be, but i would greatly prefer if they were because the rest of my code and functions as well as my analysis of the algorithm is in the context of frozensets. However I am open to see for what you have in mind.

Comment: You could speed up `logOrMore()` by computing `threshold = (1/log(sum)` at the beginning of the function and then checking `if count >= threshold:` in the `for` loop every time `count` is incremented and returning `True` if it is—thereby quitting sooner.

Comment: @martineau That is a good point. I will modify it accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So as suggested in the comments by @martineau, you can perform the threshold calculation only once at the beginning and store as a variable.

Another possible way of cleaning this up is using package called `first`. It's designed to take an iterable and find the first value which matches a condition. In your case, it sounds like you're looking for a value >= your threshold.

`pip install first`

An example from the documentation, finding the first even number in a list:

```py
from first import first
first([1, 1, 3, 4, 5], key=lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
```

You could use this to iterate your frozensets to find your condition. However, the rest of your codebase notwithstanding, you may be able to `zip()` your G and H lists together and use only one for-loop to check them.